# java.io.IOException: Broken pipe when file is downloaded

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot

I want to create Spring API which is used to stream video files. I tested these endpoints:

```
@RequestMapping(value = "/play_video1/{video_id}", method = RequestMethod.GET)
    @ResponseBody
    public void  home(Locale locale, @PathVariable("video_id") String videoId, HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response) throws IOException {

        String filePath = "/opt/videos/" + videoId + ".mp4";
        int fileSize = (int) new File(filePath).length();
        response.setContentLength(fileSize);
        response.setContentType("video");
        response.setBufferSize(fileSize);
        FileInputStream inputStream = new FileInputStream(filePath);
        ServletOutputStream outputStream = response.getOutputStream();
        int value = IOUtils.copy(inputStream, outputStream);
        System.out.println("File Size :: "+fileSize);
        System.out.println("Copied Bytes :: "+value);
        IOUtils.closeQuietly(inputStream);
        IOUtils.closeQuietly(outputStream);
        response.setStatus(HttpServletResponse.SC_OK);
    }

    @RequestMapping(value = "/play_video2/{video_id}", method = RequestMethod.GET)
    @ResponseBody public ResponseEntity<byte[]> getPreview1(@PathVariable("video_id") String video_id, HttpServletResponse response) {
        ResponseEntity<byte[]> result = null;
        try {
            String file = "/opt/videos/" + video_id + ".mp4";
            Path path = Paths.get(file);
            byte[] image = Files.readAllBytes(path);

            response.setStatus(HttpStatus.OK.value());
            HttpHeaders headers = new HttpHeaders();
            headers.setContentType(MediaType.APPLICATION_OCTET_STREAM);
            headers.setContentLength(image.length);
            result = new ResponseEntity<byte[]>(image, headers, HttpStatus.OK);
        } catch (java.nio.file.NoSuchFileException e) {
            response.setStatus(HttpStatus.NOT_FOUND.value());
        } catch (Exception e) {
            response.setStatus(HttpStatus.INTERNAL_SERVER_ERROR.value());
        }
        return result;
    }

    @RequestMapping(value = "/play_video3/{video_id}", method = RequestMethod.GET)
    @ResponseBody public void getPreview2(@PathVariable("video_id") String video_id, HttpServletResponse response) {
        try {
            String path = "/opt/videos/" + video_id + ".mp4";
            File file = new File(path);
            response.setBufferSize(64*1024);
            response.setContentType(MediaType.APPLICATION_OCTET_STREAM_VALUE);
            response.setHeader("Content-Disposition", "attachment; filename="+file.getName().replace(" ", "_"));
            InputStream iStream = new FileInputStream(file);
            IOUtils.copy(iStream, response.getOutputStream());
            response.flushBuffer();
        } catch (java.nio.file.NoSuchFileException e) {
            response.setStatus(HttpStatus.NOT_FOUND.value());
        } catch (Exception e) {
            response.setStatus(HttpStatus.INTERNAL_SERVER_ERROR.value());
        }
    }

    @RequestMapping(value = "/play_video4/{video_id}", method = RequestMethod.GET)
    @ResponseBody public FileSystemResource getPreview3(@PathVariable("video_id") String video_id, HttpServletResponse response) {
        String path = "/opt/videos/" + video_id + ".mp4";
        return new FileSystemResource(path);
    }
```

But every time I get this error:

```
17:02:54.052 [http-nio-8090-exec-5] DEBUG DispatcherServlet[traceDebug:91] - GET "/engine/product/play_video3/2", parameters={}
17:02:54.053 [http-nio-8090-exec-5] DEBUG RequestMappingHandlerMapping[getHandler:415] - Mapped to org.engine.rest.ProductController#getPreview2(String, HttpServletResponse)
17:02:54.054 [http-nio-8090-exec-5] DEBUG OpenEntityManagerInViewInterceptor[preHandle:86] - Opening JPA EntityManager in OpenEntityManagerInViewInterceptor
17:02:54.055 [http-nio-8090-exec-5] DEBUG HstsHeaderWriter[writeHeaders:169] - Not injecting HSTS header since it did not match the requestMatcher org.springframework.security.web.header.writers.HstsHeaderWriter$SecureRequestMatcher@50fe3075
17:02:54.055 [http-nio-8090-exec-5] DEBUG HttpSessionSecurityContextRepository[saveContext:351] - SecurityContext is empty or contents are anonymous - context will not be stored in HttpSession.
17:02:54.094 [http-nio-8090-exec-4] DEBUG ExceptionHandlerExceptionResolver[doResolveHandlerMethodException:398] - Using @ExceptionHandler org.engine.exception.EngineExceptionHandler#serverExceptionHandler(Exception)
17:02:54.095 [http-nio-8090-exec-4] ERROR EngineExceptionHandler[serverExceptionHandler:45] - java.io.IOException: Broken pipe
java.io.IOException: Broken pipe
        at java.base/sun.nio.ch.FileDispatcherImpl.write0(Native Method)
        at java.base/sun.nio.ch.SocketDispatcher.write(SocketDispatcher.java:47)
        at java.base/sun.nio.ch.IOUtil.writeFromNativeBuffer(IOUtil.java:113)
        at java.base/sun.nio.ch.IOUtil.write(IOUtil.java:79)
        at java.base/sun.nio.ch.IOUtil.write(IOUtil.java:50)
        at java.base/sun.nio.ch.SocketChannelImpl.write(SocketChannelImpl.java:466)
        at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.NioChannel.write(NioChannel.java:138)
        at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.NioBlockingSelector.write(NioBlockingSelector.java:101)
        at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.NioSelectorPool.write(NioSelectorPool.java:152)
        at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.NioEndpoint$NioSocketWrapper.doWrite(NioEndpoint.java:1253)
        at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.SocketWrapperBase.doWrite(SocketWrapperBase.java:764)
        at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.SocketWrapperBase.writeBlocking(SocketWrapperBase.java:584)
        at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.SocketWrapperBase.write(SocketWrapperBase.java:528)
        at org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11OutputBuffer$SocketOutputBuffer.doWrite(Http11OutputBuffer.java:546)
        at org.apache.coyote.http11.filters.IdentityOutputFilter.doWrite(IdentityOutputFilter.java:73)
        at org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11OutputBuffer.doWrite(Http11OutputBuffer.java:193)
        at org.apache.coyote.Response.doWrite(Response.java:601)
        at org.apache.catalina.connector.OutputBuffer.realWriteBytes(OutputBuffer.java:339)
        at org.apache.catalina.connector.OutputBuffer.flushByteBuffer(OutputBuffer.java:776)
        at org.apache.catalina.connector.OutputBuffer.append(OutputBuffer.java:681)
        at org.apache.catalina.connector.OutputBuffer.writeBytes(OutputBuffer.java:386)
        at org.apache.catalina.connector.OutputBuffer.write(OutputBuffer.java:364)
        at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteOutputStream.write(CoyoteOutputStream.java:96)
        at org.springframework.security.web.util.OnCommittedResponseWrapper$SaveContextServletOutputStream.write(OnCommittedResponseWrapper.java:645)
        at org.springframework.security.web.util.OnCommittedResponseWrapper$SaveContextServletOutputStream.write(OnCommittedResponseWrapper.java:645)
        at org.springframework.util.StreamUtils.copyRange(StreamUtils.java:204)
        at org.springframework.http.converter.ResourceRegionHttpMessageConverter.writeResourceRegion(ResourceRegionHttpMessageConverter.java:159)
        at org.springframework.http.converter.ResourceRegionHttpMessageConverter.writeInternal(ResourceRegionHttpMessageConverter.java:136)
        at org.springframework.http.converter.AbstractGenericHttpMessageConverter.write(AbstractGenericHttpMessageConverter.java:104)
        at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.AbstractMessageConverterMethodProcessor.writeWithMessageConverters(AbstractMessageConverterMethodProcessor.java:277)
        at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.RequestResponseBodyMethodProcessor.handleReturnValue(RequestResponseBodyMethodProcessor.java:181)
        at org.springframework.web.method.support.HandlerMethodReturnValueHandlerComposite.handleReturnValue(HandlerMethodReturnValueHandlerComposite.java:82)
        at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.ServletInvocableHandlerMethod.invokeAndHandle(ServletInvocableHandlerMethod.java:123)
        at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.invokeHandlerMethod(RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.java:878)
        at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.handleInternal(RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.java:792)
        at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.AbstractHandlerMethodAdapter.handle(AbstractHandlerMethodAdapter.java:87)
        at org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doDispatch(DispatcherServlet.java:1040)
        at org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doService(DispatcherServlet.java:943)
        at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.processRequest(FrameworkServlet.java:1006)
        at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.doGet(FrameworkServlet.java:898)
        at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:626)
        at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.service(FrameworkServlet.java:883)
        at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:733)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:231)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:166)
        at org.apache.tomcat.websocket.server.WsFilter.doFilter(WsFilter.java:53)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:193)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:166)
        at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:320)
        at org.springframework.security.web.access.intercept.FilterSecurityInterceptor.invoke(FilterSecurityInterceptor.java:126)
        at org.springframework.security.web.access.intercept.FilterSecurityInterceptor.doFilter(FilterSecurityInterceptor.java:90)
        at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:334)
        at org.springframework.security.web.access.ExceptionTranslationFilter.doFilter(ExceptionTranslationFilter.java:118)
        at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:334)
        at org.springframework.security.web.session.SessionManagementFilter.doFilter(SessionManagementFilter.java:137)
        at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:334)
        at org.springframework.security.web.authentication.AnonymousAuthenticationFilter.doFilter(AnonymousAuthenticationFilter.java:111)
        at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:334)
        at org.springframework.security.web.servletapi.SecurityContextHolderAwareRequestFilter.doFilter(SecurityContextHolderAwareRequestFilter.java:158)
        at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:334)
        at org.springframework.security.web.savedrequest.RequestCacheAwareFilter.doFilter(RequestCacheAwareFilter.java:63)
        at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:334)
        at org.springframework.security.web.authentication.logout.LogoutFilter.doFilter(LogoutFilter.java:116)
        at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:334)
        at org.springframework.security.web.header.HeaderWriterFilter.doHeadersAfter(HeaderWriterFilter.java:92)
        at org.springframework.security.web.header.HeaderWriterFilter.doFilterInternal(HeaderWriterFilter.java:77)
        at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:119)
        at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:334)
        at org.springframework.security.web.context.SecurityContextPersistenceFilter.doFilter(SecurityContextPersistenceFilter.java:105)
        at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:334)
        at org.springframework.security.web.context.request.async.WebAsyncManagerIntegrationFilter.doFilterInternal(WebAsyncManagerIntegrationFilter.java:56)
        at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:119)
        at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:334)
        at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy.doFilterInternal(FilterChainProxy.java:215)
        at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:178)
        at org.springframework.web.filter.DelegatingFilterProxy.invokeDelegate(DelegatingFilterProxy.java:358)
        at org.springframework.web.filter.DelegatingFilterProxy.doFilter(DelegatingFilterProxy.java:271)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:193)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:166)
        at org.springframework.web.filter.RequestContextFilter.doFilterInternal(RequestContextFilter.java:100)
        at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:119)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:193)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:166)
        at org.springframework.web.filter.FormContentFilter.doFilterInternal(FormContentFilter.java:93)
        at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:119)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:193)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:166)
        at org.springframework.boot.actuate.metrics.web.servlet.WebMvcMetricsFilter.doFilterInternal(WebMvcMetricsFilter.java:93)
        at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:119)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:193)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:166)
        at org.springframework.web.filter.CharacterEncodingFilter.doFilterInternal(CharacterEncodingFilter.java:201)
        at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:119)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:193)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:166)
        at org.springframework.web.filter.CorsFilter.doFilterInternal(CorsFilter.java:92)
        at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:119)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:193)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:166)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:202)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:97)
        at org.apache.catalina.authenticator.AuthenticatorBase.invoke(AuthenticatorBase.java:542)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:143)
        at org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:92)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngineValve.invoke(StandardEngineValve.java:78)
        at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:343)
        at org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11Processor.service(Http11Processor.java:374)
        at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProcessorLight.process(AbstractProcessorLight.java:65)
        at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol$ConnectionHandler.process(AbstractProtocol.java:868)
        at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.NioEndpoint$SocketProcessor.doRun(NioEndpoint.java:1590)
        at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.SocketProcessorBase.run(SocketProcessorBase.java:49)
        at java.base/java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1128)
        at java.base/java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:628)
        at org.apache.tomcat.util.threads.TaskThread$WrappingRunnable.run(TaskThread.java:61)
        at java.base/java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:835)
17:02:54.097 [http-nio-8090-exec-4] DEBUG HttpEntityMethodProcessor[writeWithMessageConverters:210] - Found 'Content-Type:application/json' in response
17:02:54.097 [http-nio-8090-exec-4] DEBUG HttpEntityMethodProcessor[traceDebug:91] - Writing [org.engine.exception.ErrorResponseDTO@6a1f296e]
17:02:54.098 [http-nio-8090-exec-4] WARN  ExceptionHandlerExceptionResolver[doResolveHandlerMethodException:414] - Failure in @ExceptionHandler org.engine.exception.EngineExceptionHandler#serverExceptionHandler(Exception)
org.apache.catalina.connector.ClientAbortException: java.io.IOException: Broken pipe
        at org.apache.catalina.connector.OutputBuffer.realWriteBytes(OutputBuffer.java:351)
        at org.apache.catalina.connector.OutputBuffer.flushByteBuffer(OutputBuffer.java:776)
        at org.apache.catalina.connector.OutputBuffer.append(OutputBuffer.java:681)
        at org.apache.catalina.connector.OutputBuffer.writeBytes(OutputBuffer.java:386)
        at org.apache.catalina.connector.OutputBuffer.write(OutputBuffer.java:364)
        at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteOutputStream.write(CoyoteOutputStream.java:96)
        at org.springframework.security.web.util.OnCommittedResponseWrapper$SaveContextServletOutputStream.write(OnCommittedResponseWrapper.java:645)
        at org.springframework.security.web.util.OnCommittedResponseWrapper$SaveContextServletOutputStream.write(OnCommittedResponseWrapper.java:645)
        at com.fasterxml.jackson.core.json.UTF8JsonGenerator._flushBuffer(UTF8JsonGenerator.java:2176)
        at com.fasterxml.jackson.core.json.UTF8JsonGenerator.flush(UTF8JsonGenerator.java:1190)
        at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.ObjectWriter.writeValue(ObjectWriter.java:1008)
        at org.springframework.http.converter.json.AbstractJackson2HttpMessageConverter.writeInternal(AbstractJackson2HttpMessageConverter.java:342)
        at org.springframework.http.converter.AbstractGenericHttpMessageConverter.write(AbstractGenericHttpMessageConverter.java:104)
        at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.AbstractMessageConverterMethodProcessor.writeWithMessageConverters(AbstractMessageConverterMethodProcessor.java:277)
        at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.HttpEntityMethodProcessor.handleReturnValue(HttpEntityMethodProcessor.java:219)
        at org.springframework.web.method.support.HandlerMethodReturnValueHandlerComposite.handleReturnValue(HandlerMethodReturnValueHandlerComposite.java:82)
        at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.ServletInvocableHandlerMethod.invokeAndHandle(ServletInvocableHandlerMethod.java:123)
        at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.ExceptionHandlerExceptionResolver.doResolveHandlerMethodException(ExceptionHandlerExceptionResolver.java:403)
        at org.springframework.web.servlet.handler.AbstractHandlerMethodExceptionResolver.doResolveException(AbstractHandlerMethodExceptionResolver.java:61)
        at org.springframework.web.servlet.handler.AbstractHandlerExceptionResolver.resolveException(AbstractHandlerExceptionResolver.java:141)
        at org.springframework.web.servlet.handler.HandlerExceptionResolverComposite.resolveException(HandlerExceptionResolverComposite.java:80)
        at org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.processHandlerException(DispatcherServlet.java:1300)
        at org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.processDispatchResult(DispatcherServlet.java:1111)
        at org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doDispatch(DispatcherServlet.java:1057)
        at org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doService(DispatcherServlet.java:943)
        at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.processRequest(FrameworkServlet.java:1006)
        at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.doGet(FrameworkServlet.java:898)
        at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:626)
        at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.service(FrameworkServlet.java:883)
        at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:733)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:231)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:166)
        at org.apache.tomcat.websocket.server.WsFilter.doFilter(WsFilter.java:53)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:193)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:166)
        at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:320)
        at org.springframework.security.web.access.intercept.FilterSecurityInterceptor.invoke(FilterSecurityInterceptor.java:126)
        at org.springframework.security.web.access.intercept.FilterSecurityInterceptor.doFilter(FilterSecurityInterceptor.java:90)
        at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:334)
        at org.springframework.security.web.access.ExceptionTranslationFilter.doFilter(ExceptionTranslationFilter.java:118)
        at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:334)
        at org.springframework.security.web.session.SessionManagementFilter.doFilter(SessionManagementFilter.java:137)
        at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:334)
        at org.springframework.security.web.authentication.AnonymousAuthenticationFilter.doFilter(AnonymousAuthenticationFilter.java:111)
        at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:334)
        at org.springframework.security.web.servletapi.SecurityContextHolderAwareRequestFilter.doFilter(SecurityContextHolderAwareRequestFilter.java:158)
        at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:334)
        at org.springframework.security.web.savedrequest.RequestCacheAwareFilter.doFilter(RequestCacheAwareFilter.java:63)
        at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:334)
        at org.springframework.security.web.authentication.logout.LogoutFilter.doFilter(LogoutFilter.java:116)
        at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:334)
        at org.springframework.security.web.header.HeaderWriterFilter.doHeadersAfter(HeaderWriterFilter.java:92)
        at org.springframework.security.web.header.HeaderWriterFilter.doFilterInternal(HeaderWriterFilter.java:77)
        at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:119)
        at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:334)
        at org.springframework.security.web.context.SecurityContextPersistenceFilter.doFilter(SecurityContextPersistenceFilter.java:105)
        at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:334)
        at org.springframework.security.web.context.request.async.WebAsyncManagerIntegrationFilter.doFilterInternal(WebAsyncManagerIntegrationFilter.java:56)
        at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:119)
        at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:334)
        at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy.doFilterInternal(FilterChainProxy.java:215)
        at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:178)
        at org.springframework.web.filter.DelegatingFilterProxy.invokeDelegate(DelegatingFilterProxy.java:358)
        at org.springframework.web.filter.DelegatingFilterProxy.doFilter(DelegatingFilterProxy.java:271)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:193)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:166)
        at org.springframework.web.filter.RequestContextFilter.doFilterInternal(RequestContextFilter.java:100)
        at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:119)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:193)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:166)
        at org.springframework.web.filter.FormContentFilter.doFilterInternal(FormContentFilter.java:93)
        at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:119)                     
        Suppressed: org.apache.catalina.connector.ClientAbortException: java.io.IOException: Broken pipe
                at org.apache.catalina.connector.OutputBuffer.realWriteBytes(OutputBuffer.java:351)
                at org.apache.catalina.connector.OutputBuffer.flushByteBuffer(OutputBuffer.java:776)
                at org.apache.catalina.connector.OutputBuffer.doFlush(OutputBuffer.java:298)
                at org.apache.catalina.connector.OutputBuffer.close(OutputBuffer.java:251)
                at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteOutputStream.close(CoyoteOutputStream.java:157)
                at org.springframework.security.web.util.OnCommittedResponseWrapper$SaveContextServletOutputStream.close(OnCommittedResponseWrapper.java:526)
                at org.springframework.security.web.util.OnCommittedResponseWrapper$SaveContextServletOutputStream.close(OnCommittedResponseWrapper.java:526)
                at com.fasterxml.jackson.core.json.UTF8JsonGenerator.close(UTF8JsonGenerator.java:1231)
                at org.springframework.http.converter.json.AbstractJackson2HttpMessageConverter.writeInternal(AbstractJackson2HttpMessageConverter.java:346)
                ... 90 common frames omitted
        Caused by: java.io.IOException: Broken pipe
                at java.base/sun.nio.ch.FileDispatcherImpl.write0(Native Method)
                at java.base/sun.nio.ch.SocketDispatcher.write(SocketDispatcher.java:47)                                 
                ... 98 common frames omitted
Caused by: java.io.IOException: Broken pipe          org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11OutputBuffer$SocketOutputBuffer.doWrite(Http11OutputBuffer.java:546)
        at org.apache.coyote.http11.filters.IdentityOutputFilter.doWrite(IdentityOutputFilter.java:73)
        at org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11OutputBuffer.doWrite(Http11OutputBuffer.java:193)
        at org.apache.coyote.Response.doWrite(Response.java:601)
        at org.apache.catalina.connector.OutputBuffer.realWriteBytes(OutputBuffer.java:339)
        ... 101 common frames omitted
17:02:54.101 [http-nio-8090-exec-4] DEBUG OpenEntityManagerInViewInterceptor[afterCompletion:111] - Closing JPA EntityManager in OpenEntityManagerInViewInterceptor
17:02:54.101 [http-nio-8090-exec-4] DEBUG DispatcherServlet[logResult:1101] - Failed to complete request: org.apache.catalina.connector.ClientAbortException: java.io.IOException: Broken pipe
```

Do you know how I can fix this issue?